# I copied a folder with copy&paste instead of 'xcopy'. How to fix that?

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, robocopy, xcopy

I copied a folder  (Windows Server 2003) with copy-paste instead of 'xcopy' or 'robocopy'. Now I lost the original permissions, and I can't re-do the copy process (can't access the original folder).

How to set the permissions to the target folder? Should I set permissions manually on the new folder (just as I think the permissions should be)? any other trick?